# TS2322: Type '(new () =&gt; typeof Rectangle)[]' is not assignable to type 'Rectangle[]'

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types

I have a function that stamps copies of classes. It takes a class and returns as many copies of classes as I specified. But the problem is not in the function but in its signature. To create new classes I need a function `new` and to connect it I did `extends { new(): T }`. I need it to return an array of classes with their type, but instead it returns `(new () => typeof Rectangle)[]` and I can't figure out what the problem is. Here is the code.

```js
class Rectangle {
    w!: number;
    h!: number;
}
class Circle {
    radius!: number;
}


function stampFigures<T extends { new (): T } >(someClass: T, count: number): T[] {
    let a = []
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
        a.push(new someClass());

    return a;
}

let a: Rectangle[] = stampFigures(Rectangle, 10); //here i need Rectangle[] but i got (new () => typeof Rectangle)[]
let b: Circle[] = stampFigures(Circle, 20) //and here

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to infer an [instance type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) of class:

```js
class Rectangle {
  w!: number;
  h!: number;
}
class Circle {
  radius!: number;
}


function stampFigures<
  Klass extends { new(): any }
>(someClass: Klass, count: number) {
  let a: InstanceType<Klass>[] = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
    a.push(new someClass());

  return a;
}

let a = stampFigures(Rectangle, 10); //  Rectangle[]
let b = stampFigures(Circle, 20) // Circle[]

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W48DBW)

YOu can also check my [article](https://catchts.com/oop-style#handle_keyof)

If you are interested in safest solution, you can create base class and extends your classes with `tag` property. In other words, discriminate it.

```js
class Shape {
  tag: string = ''
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
  tag = 'Rectangle'
  w!: number;
  h!: number;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  tag = 'Circle'

  radius!: number;
}


function stampFigures<
  Klass extends typeof Shape,
  Instance extends InstanceType<Klass>
>(someClass: Klass & (new () => Instance), count: number) {
  let a = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
    a.push(new someClass());

  return a;
}

let a = stampFigures(Rectangle, 10); //  Rectangle[]
let b = stampFigures(Circle, 20) // Circle[]

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxBdXw)

Comment: So if this real maybe you can do this without new() any becouse any is not so good

Comment: Sure, you can use `Klass extends typeof Rectangle | typeof Circle` but then you need to overload your function [example](https://tsplay.dev/Nabx6m)

Comment: @Quartz_ Made an update